# trying to complete Xcode tip calculator, but receiving an error

Tags: xcode

```
//convert slider value to NSDecimalNumber
let  sliderValue = NSDecimalNumber (integer : Int(customTipPercentSlider.value))
```

Argument labels '(integer:)' do not match any available overloads is the error I'm receiving, can someone help me please

how do i correct this error?

Answer (score 0):

The initializer for `NSDecimalNumber` requires `Decimal` - not an `Int`

Use this:

```
let  sliderValue = NSDecimalNumber (decimal : Decimal(1.0))
```